# How to manage Arraylist position?

Tags: android, object, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

i have Arraylist

```
private ArrayList<Items> mArrayList
```

and i have added item in this Arraylist and bind to adapter. After binding i have got the below output:

```
position(Arraylist)   item_name
0                       abc
1                       chf
2                       tiy
3                       trf
4                       lkj
5                       xyz
```

So now i have `two buttons 1)Remove and 2) undo`

On Remove button click event i am removing item .so i have used below code:

```
mArrayList.remove(0);

mItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So it is removed item from `0` position .
after that my data is

```
position(Arraylist)   item_name

0                       chf
1                       tiy
2                       trf
3                       lkj
4                       xyz
```

So now after this i have written below code for undo the last item:

```
item tm = (HomeScreenProduct) Object;
mArrayList.add(0, tm);
mItemdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So now the last item is not added to 0th position.

I want like when i click on undo button then the last item which was removed it should be set on 0th position.

So when i click on undo i want the output like

```
 position(Arraylist)   item_name
    0                       abc
    1                       chf
    2                       tiy
    3                       trf
    4                       lkj
    5                       xyz
```

Becasue each time after removing item the position will change.

so just simple i want to set the last removed item to `0th position`

How can i do this?

Comment: `mArrayList.add(0, tm);` should add it to the 0 position

Comment: But it is worked perfect for last item. But it is not working if i have lots of items.

Comment: please describe not working

Answer (score 0):

ok you will have this problem with every position. For example if you delete item on position `n` and you want to undo it you need to move (copy) each item from position `n` to `n+1`, from `n+1` to `n+2` etc. Than you can set removed item to position `n`. I hope I've described it in clear way :)

// EDIT

this is just pseudo code but it shows my thoughts

```
int newPosition = pos;
Items undoObject = tm;
ArrayList<Items> oldList = mArrayList;
ArrayList<Items> newList = new ArrayList<Items>();
int i = 0;
for(Items item : oldList) {
    if(i == newPosition) {
    newList.add(undoObject);
    } else {
    newList.add(item);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Logically its clear. But i am not able to perform this.  I have also try to bind adapter again after add to 0th postion but is not working.

Comment: you need to add my logick to undo method. You can even using temporary list to copy elements. You do this by adding element from old list to new and when you have the undo position you add it as a next element, after that you again add items from old to new. this will do the trick

Comment: check my code. it is not 100% but it should show you what we're talking about :)

Comment: Ok. i will try it. :-) . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you remove one item you should store the item value and position.

```
mPositionRemoved = mPositionToRemove;
mRemovedValue = mArrayList[mPositionToRemove];
mArrayList.remove(mPositionToRemove);
```

When you undo:

```
mRemovedValue = mArrayList[mPositionToRemove];
mArrayList.add(mPositionRemoved, mRemovedValue);
```

This will move the following items as needed

Answer (score 0):

create another temporary arraylist. and when you do undo operation add that deleted item in temporary arraylist check below

```
tempArraylist.clear(); 
tempArraylist.add(item);    
tempArraylist.addll(mainArraylist); //this will add all the rest items after 0th position
mainArraylist= tempArraylist;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

this will do your work :-)

Comment: where i can put the `mArrayList.add(0, tm);` ?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention.sorry .  you will have to empty your tempArraylist by .clear . i am updating my answer on top.  and you dont have to specify position for the item when adding. it will automaticaly take 0th positioin

Comment: and Please show me the log where it is crashing. i have a feeling you must have not initialized tempArraylist.

Comment: should i have to take tempArraylist as `ArrayList<Itme> tempArraylist` or `jsut Arraylist tempArraylist ` ?

Comment: yea it has to be initialized lik this ArrayList<Itme> tempArraylist = new ArrayList<Itme>();

Comment: Still it is not working. `When i click on undo button first and then click on removed button then the last item set to 0th position..`

Comment: if possible then i can share my screen. so you can check it.

Comment: @deepak. seems to be you are confused with the flow of your code. just don't allow user to click on undo button until and unless he removes one item from list. you have to handle such case's. otherwise isn't that solution works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void remove(index){
    mArrayList.remove(index);
    mItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void undo(int index, Object object) {
    mArrayList.add(index, object);
    mItemdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private Item getItem(int index) {
    return mArrayList.get(index);
}

int index = 0;
Item tm = getItem(index);

remove(index);
undo(index, tm);
```

Comment: it has problem like when i first click on undo button and after that if i press removed button then it works fine. But when i first press removed button then press undo button then it is not wokrs.

Comment: So why would you undo if you have not pressed remove button, you need make undo clickable only if you remove something

Comment: i have also tried that. Now im my mArrayList has size = 6(0 to 5) now when i press remove button then it will call the remove(index) where index=0.
After that the new mArrayList size = 5(0 to 4) so the 1st position is set to the 0th position after press remove button. 
So when i click on undo button then it is try to add 0th position which has already data.

Comment: if you insert at index 0, then all the other element indices will be shifted of +1 position. I will test the code right now

Comment: Oh..i have the debug the code. It is working fine.. but the data is not visible again.!! In debug it shows perfect.

Comment: so should i have to bind again the adapter ? i have custom adapter.

Comment: yeah `mlistView.setAdapter(mItemAdapter);` should run before `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89102/discussion-between-deepak-and-meda).